# Angular custom webpack config enable CSS modules

Tags: css, angular, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I'm trying to apply CSS modules concept agains my angular app, to order embed it into existing frontend with CSS which unfortunately overlaps. My project uses scss, I want webpack "modulize" my CSS after CSS if formed from scss on last build step I think.

I want to use CSS loader of webpack to achieve this.
But I couldn't make it work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack
to order customize my webpack config. 
I've tried to apply the next configuration

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

and got this error

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | exports = module.exports = require("../../../../css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js")(false);
```

I've tried to find and add css loader into existing

```
module.exports = (config, options) => {

  const rules = config.module.rules || [];
  rules.forEach(rule => {
    if (String(rule.test) === String(/\.css$/)) {

      rule.use.push({ loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true }})

    }
  });
  return config;
};
```

Getting the same error. How to make it work?

**Update 1:**

I found that angular uses postcss which also provides this functionality as a plugin, postcss-modules. Also still can't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to implement [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) in Angular with the help of [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) as you suggested.

However, my solution use [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) and [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules) instead of the `css-loader` to hash the styles.

[postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) hash all the styles, then [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules) replaces the class names on the html files by the hashed class names.

I documented my solution here:

- Live Demo: https://angular-css-modules.herokuapp.com/
- Github Repo: https://github.com/gquinteros93/angular-css-modules
- Article with the step by step: https://indepth.dev/angular-css-modules/

I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Not working anymore.